# カウントアップの速度を指定した2次関数に従って表示させたい

Tags: javascript

初めて質問を投稿させていただきます。
Javascriptも勉強してまだ間もない初心者であるため、質問に不備がありましたら申し訳ありません。

ある関数により、1以上のランダムな数値が返ります。
1からスタートしその数までカウントアップをさせ、それをhtml上に表示させたいのですが、一定の速度ではなくカウントアップしていくにつれて早くカウントアップさせたいです。

しかしどうしても指定した2次関数 y = x^2/100 + 1 (xはカウントアップが完了する時間、yは関数により返ったランダムな数値。)を組み込むことに苦戦しています。

カウントアップは、関数により返ってきた数値の大小にかかわらず、常に上記の関数に従った秒数で完了させます（y = 100 でも y = 1000 でもカウントアップが2を通過する時点では必ず10秒）。

上記カウントアップは、[bustabit](https://www.bustabit.com/play) というギャンブルのサイトで表示されているようなカウントアップを参考にしています。

実装の方針を助言していただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

※追記※
下記コードになりますが、speed変数の数値は最初の代入時点で固定してしまうため当然一定の速度でカウントアップしてしまいます。

```
let num = 1;
let goal = 500; //本来はランダムな数字
// y = x**2 / 100 + 1
// →→→ x = 10 * Math.sqrt(y - 1)
let speed = 10 * Math.sqrt(goal - 1);

setInterval(function(){
    if(num <= goal){
    document.getElementById("hoge").textContent = num;
    num++;
    }
},speed);
```

Comment: まずは御自身で記入した動かなくてもいいのでソースコードを追記してください

Comment: @keitaro_so 遅ればせながら追記させていただきました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

大事なのは、開始時刻と現在時刻の差を取ることです。また、JavaScriptでこういったアニメーションを行うには `setInterval()` よりは `requestAnimationFrame()` を使いましょう。

```js
let goal = 500; //本来はランダムな数字
const startTime = performance.now();

function runAnimation(currentTime) {
  let x = (currentTime - startTime) / 1000;
  let num = Math.floor(x * x / 100 + 1);
  if (num <= goal) {
    document.getElementById("hoge").textContent = num;
    requestAnimationFrame(runAnimation);
  }
}
requestAnimationFrame(runAnimation);
```

こういった用途には、通常 `requestAnimationFrame()` を用います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！
無知で申し訳ありません。currentTimeが理解できなかったため、
runAnimation関数に引数を取らず、x定義時のcurrentTimeをperformance.now()に変更して調整を行った結果、思い通りに動いています。

currentTime は定義漏れでしょうか？
どこでどのような内容を定義するのでしょうか？

Comment: currentTimeはrunAnimation()の引数ですから、runAnimation()を呼ぶコードが用意して渡すものです。この場合はブラウザが用意して渡すので、ユーザのコードで用意する必要はありません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
まだ勉強不十分なため、貴殿の回答を参考に色々と調べてみたいと思います。